# How can we compare a string with the values of enum elements in Java

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum `Foo`

```
public enum Foo {

    A("first"),

    B("second"),

    private final String value;

    private Foo(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String value() {
        return this.value;
    }

}
```

Below I am trying to check if a string is contained in my enum.

```
public boolean isValidFoo(String fooStr) {
return EnumSet.allOf(Foo.class)
                        .contains(Foo.valueOf(fooStr.toUpperCase()));
}
```

This works when I send `A` or `B` for `fooStr`.
How to make it work when I send `first` or `second` for `fooStr`?

Comment: don't call valueOf(), call value(); that's the name of your method that returns the value. Better yet, rename it getValue(), it 'll make the distinction more clear

Comment: You can create a Set with `Arrays.stream(Foo.values()).map(Foo::value).collect(toSet())`, store this Set in a static field somewhere, and use `theSet.contains(fooStr)`.

Comment: possibilities, depends on usage: use streams with map and filter to find enum; static `HashMap` created at *start* mapping values to enum; a static `Set` also created at *start* containing all values; or ...

Comment: @Stultuske I do not understand how calling `value` would help in that? (`contains` checks for  an enum instance)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger it's the name of his getter, that's how he gets the value.

Comment: I know, but will not work like "don't call valueOf(), call value()" - and call `value()` of what? `contains` just search for an instance of the enum - is is not functional either (as I know)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare string to enum type in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682553/how-to-compare-string-to-enum-type-in-java)

Comment: not duplicate of previous (about finding enum by name); **related**, but has some ideas, need changes:  [Finding enum value with Java 8 Stream API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27807232/85421)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this..

```
public boolean isValidFoo(String fooStr) {
    return Arrays.stream(Foo.values())
            .anyMatch(e -> e.value.equals(fooStr));
}
```

Comment: add `map(Foo::value)` instead of using `e.value` (when using functional, lets stay functional)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method

```
  public static Foo getEnum(String value) {
        for (Foo foo : Foo.values()) {
            if (foo.value.equals(value)) {
                return foo;
            }
        }
        return null;
  }
```